# Port forwarding work on virtual machines but not on host

Tags: iptables

I use this iptables config
It simply redirect to port 21 the connection of 2121(used
to run ftp as user instead of root)

```
  *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [200:39210]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [6:360]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [21:1323]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [21:1323]
    -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2121 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:21
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Sun Jan 24 19:17:55 2016
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.4.20 on Sun Jan 24 19:17:55 2016
    *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [2996:188699]
    -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 2121 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -d 192.168.0.2/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Sun Jan 24 19:17:55 2016
```

ip4 forwarding is enabled
This config works perfect on two virtual machines: one slackware,one centos6
But not my host with slackware.
What can i check?
I forgot: the server ftp is on a chroot

Comment: Which IP address did you use for the host rule?

Comment: Same ip,i use same ip because i want to run ftp as user not as root,and user cannot use 21 wich is privileged port

Comment: What is `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables` returning on the host?

Comment: By the way if your server listens on port 2121 you should reverse ports of your PREROUTING rule

Comment: This configuration works fine,but not when is in chroot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution finally found.
ftp is on chroot,and is pure-ftpd
This line

```
Bind                      10.2.2.1,2121
```

Don't work on chroot,but work out of chroot

This line

```
Bind                      *,2121
```

Works perfect in chroot

I use this firewall script

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp --sport 2121 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2121 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2121
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m tcp -p tcp -o lo --dport 21 -j REDIRECT --to-port 2121
```